# Как задать GameObject (игровой объект) при помощи RaycastHit в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу так, чтобы объект directionalItem стал равен объекту в который попал луч, но у меня юнити пишет ошибку, что объект не выбран (NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object). Что делать?

```
    private GameObject directionalItem;
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, ray.direction * rayDistance);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, rayDistance))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Object")
            {
                directionalItem = hit.collider.transform.gameObject;
            }
        }
    }
```

ещё я пробовал hit.collider.gameObject и hit.transform.gameObject, но всё равно ничего не работает

Comment: _Что делать?_ - [Отлаживать код](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019). Или хотя-бы указать в коде, в какой строке и на что именно ругается.

Comment: У вас просто не создан или не назначен объект directionalItem или тот объект в который попадает луч .... Можно более детально описать ....принтскрин консоли и в инспекторе принтскрин скрипта который вешаете на объект но я подозреваю вам просто надо сделать  GameObject directionalItem = new GameObject();